# Character suppression at newline

Tags: line-breaking, conditionals

I am attempting to typeset a list of names separated by specific characters, e.g. `John Doe | Jane Doe | John Doe | Jane Doe | John Doe | Jane Doe | ...`.

This list is to be `input{}` into various documents with different text widths. I am now looking for a way to suppress the separation character at the linebreaks without having to do that manually. Can anyone suggest such a conditional method?

Thanks!

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\geometry{paperwidth=140mm, paperheight=200mm}

\begin{document}
John Doe | Jane Doe | John Doe | Jane Doe | John Doe | Jane Doe | ...
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\geometry{paperwidth=140mm, paperheight=200mm}

\def\zz{\ifhmode\unskip\fi\discretionary{}{}{\hbox{ | }}}
\begin{document}
John Doe \zz Jane Doe \zz John Doe \zz Jane Doe \zz John Doe \zz Jane Doe \zz ...
\end{document}
```